# toDateString inconsistent with getDay?

Tags: javascript

I have a date object:

```
var thedate = new Date("2012-05-02T11:00:00.000+0000");
```

When I do `getMonth()` I get 4, but when I do `getDay()` I get 3? I want to make it so that when I call `getDay`, I get what’s reflected in the original string (2). I could just subtract 1 from `getDay()`, but I’m not sure if that’s the right way to do it, and whether it applies to all dates.

Comment: It's a good idea to read the fine documentation.  getDate() gives you the day of the month; getDay() gets you the day of the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), `getMonth` will return a number in the range 0-11 (so 0 is for January), and `getDay` will return the day of the week in the range 0-6 (so 0 is for Sunday). If you want to get the day in month, you should use `getDate`, which will return a number in the range 1-31.

Answer (score 1):

`getDay`/`getMonth` will return the index of the day, which starts from 0, therefore +1.

> getDay()  Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)

Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: W3Schools isn’t really a great reference, and this answer is not really correct either, from what I can tell by “+1”.